# Javascript get value from an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object with key value pairs inside an array:

```
var data = [
  {
  "errorCode":100,
  "message":{},
  "name":"InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.Hosts.HostNumberOfEntries",
  "value":"2"
  }
];
```

I want to get the value of "value" key in the object. ie, the output should be "2".

I tried this:

```
console.log(data[value]);
console.log(data.value);
```

Both logging "undefined". I saw similar questions in SO itself. But, I couldn't figure out a solution for my problem.

Comment: The given json is array of object. so you need to specify index number to get value

Comment: console.log(data[0].Value);

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are trying to get the value from the first element of the array. ie, `data[0]`. This will work:

```
console.log(data[0].value);
```

If you have multiple elements in the array, use JavaScript [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function or some other function like [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate through the arrays.

```
data.map(x => console.log(x.value));

data.forEach(x => console.log(x.value));
```

Comment: what if my array element is in an object and how can I retrieve value?  eg: `[ { totalAmount: '150' }, { totalAmount: '10' } ]`

Comment: `const objArr = [ { totalAmount: '150' }, { totalAmount: '10' } ];  console.log(objArr[0].totalAmount);` will return 150.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the **map** property of the array. Never try to get the value by hardcoding the index value, as mentioned in the above answers, Which might get you in trouble. For your case the below code will works.

```
data.map(x => x.value)
```

Comment: This should be the right answer, you can't rely on [0]

Answer (score 5):

`data` is `Array` you need get first element in `Array` and then get `Value` property from `Object`,

```js
var data = [{
  "ErrorCode":100,
  "Message":{},
  "Name":"InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.Hosts.HostNumberOfEntries",
  "Value":"2"
}];

console.log(data[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this... 
Actually Here `Data` is an array of object so you first need to access that object and then you can access `Value` of that object.

```js
var data = [
  {
  "ErrorCode":100,
  "Message":{},
  "Name":"InternetGatewayDevice.LANDevice.1.Hosts.HostNumberOfEntries",
  "Value":"2"
  }
];

alert(data[0].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to read is an object which an element of an array, so you should first fetch the element of array by specifying its index like
data[0] and then read a property of the fetched object, i.e. .value,

so the complete syntax would be data[0].value
Hope it helps !